# Springboot data schema setup

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a project in Thymeleaf & Springboot.

I need to know the best way to setup the schema between three entities.

Event

Project

Task

**The relationships**

Event to Project is ManyToOne

Project to Event is OneToMany

Project to Task is OneToMany

Task to Project is ManyToOne

**Entities**

```
public Event() {}
@Id
private Long id
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Project project;

public Project() {}
@Id
private Long id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Task> tasks;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
private List<Event> event;

public Task() {}
@Id
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
private Project project;
```

As it stands at the moment:

1. Events can be created on the event UI and saved correctly.
2. The project UI screen (which contains some information from Event) can create a project and on the same UI create tasks but upon clicking submit all the information enters the database but task table gets the task but the FK project_id is empty.

On the controller for the get and post project I am passing in Event into the model as I need some information from Event on the plan screen.

Is there a better way to display on the plan UI some info from Event but CRUD plan.
Why is FK project_id empty?

**UPDATE**

I have tried :

```
public Task() {}
@Id
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;
```

Still doesn't get a project_id on task table.

Comment: About the UI part of the question: how you design your UI is your business, it should be as helpful to the user as possible independent of your backend architecture. You are building the UI *for the user* not for your server so put yourself in his shoes. But it seems odd you submit all information on the page. Usually, REST goes hand in hand with Ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

> Why is FK project_id empty?

You are missing the annotation that maps the many-to-one relation to a column where the FK is. Also, if you want to persist the Task instance and let your JPA framework automatically persist the project, you should define a cascade strategy.

```
@JoinColumn(name="project_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade=ALL)
private Project project;
```

Take a look at some JPA documentation, here's a nice free book:

[about many-to-one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne#Example_of_a_ManyToOne_relationship_annotations)

[about cascading on relationships](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading)

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html)

Comment: I tried @JoinColumn(name="project_id) on the ManyToOne for private Project project. Still didnt save project_id on task.

Comment: I presume the project must save first, so when it comes time to save the task, the task knows what project to be associated with.

Comment: You shouldn't have to bother with saving the objects manually and in the correct order. That can be done by the JPA framework automatically if your mapping is correct and if you have a correct cascading strategy. Anyway, from my experience, you will lose more time by guessing how it works and troubleshooting bad code than if you fast-read some documentation and then get it right from the first try.

Comment: Still I think he tried your answer but it didn't fix the FK issue